# StackRouter has error in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

i want to use stack router in react native with react-navigation package 
but when i use it i get this error

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
>   instantiateReactComponent
>       D:\react-native\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\ReactNativeStack-dev.js:1984:75
>   instantiateChild

my code:

```
 import React,{Component} from 'react'
 import {StyleSheet, Text, View, AppRegistry} from 'react-native'

 import{StackRouter} from 'react-navigation'
 export default class Activity extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

}

render() {
    return (
        <Text> title:adsfdsf </Text>
    )
}
}

const AwesomeProject = StackRouter({
Home: {screen: Activity},

 }, {
initialRouteName: 'Home',
 })
 AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

Answer (score -1):

You're importing the wrong component from `react-navigation`. It's `StackNavigator`.

```
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

const AwesomeProject = StackRouter(
 {
   Home: {screen: Activity},
 }, 
 {
   initialRouteName: 'Home',
 }
)
```

Comment: i want to use stackrouter instead of stackNavigator @kyle-roach

Comment: StackRouter is the underlying API of StackNavigator